# How can I update the Vuejs Component when we get the html from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I've created a Vue.js Single File Component, and on page refresh the Component loads from the template perfectly, but on click of a button I run an ajax request to get the updated HTML, which inside calls my Vue component, and this is what I get:

`<quantity-changer-custom :control-name="'qty[198]'" :quantity="1"></quantity-changer-custom>`

Is there a way to import the component or something, or should I remove my component from the single file and write it inside the HTML where it is used?

Comment: You don't send back HTML but the values instead, and update your app state based on them. This will trigger a re-render of the template, which is supposed to render your app state to be able to reflect the changes. You need to completely forget the concept of "changing the DOM directly" when working with a front-end framework like Vue.

Comment: @ChrisG The reason I am going this way is because the cart is getting updated with Laravel, and thought that there may be a way to rerender my vue component. Thanks a lot for your answer!